# Make Kinetic JS Rectangle multi-clickable

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas, kineticjs

Can I make a Kinetic.Rect multi-clickable. Can I fill the rectangle multiple images and open different things on click of each image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. But better and much cleaner way is create a group of rectangles and set events and fills for each.

Comment: Ok....Can I make only one edge of the rectangle rounded while keeping other edges sharp???